# Пометка правок как «малых»

Tags: предложение, правки

Изменённое сообщение выносится на заглавную даже если подправить в нём запятую. Чем выше сообщение в обновляющемся списке вопросов, тем больше вероятность получить за него плюс, — почему, вероятно, некоторые участники негативно относятся к незначительным изменениям, а может кто-то и действительно пытался так набить репутацию.

Предлагаю [по аналогии с Википедией](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) добавить галочку «Малое изменение».

[image: Малое изменение]

Которую рекомендовалось бы использовать, когда правка не добавляет в вопрос или ответ уточнений, дополнений или обновлений, а носит оформительский характер либо исправляет недочёты в правописании. Правки, помеченные как «малые», не будут выноситься на заглавную.

Comment: В общем и целом - давайте не будем делать из Stack Overflow Википедию. Думаю, это неудачный путь.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Забудьте про существование "главной" страницы. На нашем сайте старая версия движка, в новой версии "главной" страницы нет. Соответственно, и проблемы с правками и "апаньем" нет.

В новой версии существует только сортировка по дате последней правки. Добавить ещё сортировку по дате последней существенной правки? По-моему, это будет чрезмерно сложно, все только запутаются.

Раньше для войны с "апаньем" вопроса существовало превращение поста в вики после определённого числа правок. Сейчас от этого избавились, значит, проблема нечестного "апанья" не стоит так остро.

Так как в старой системе никто менять сортировку не будет, а в новой ваше предложение не решает проблему, то реализовать идею не представляется возможным. Кроме того, цепочка мелких правок запросто может стать крупной правкой. Это открывает простор для спама, войн правок и прочих нехороших вещей.

Comment: А когда русский Stack Overflow перейдёт на новую версию движка?

Comment: @СашаЧерных Этот вопрос следует адресовать Николасу. И то не гарантирую, что он сможет сказать.

Comment: Это открывает простор для спама, войн правок и прочих нехороших вещей. — в комментариях к другим ответам обсудили, что функционал для опытных участников, появляется при достижении определённой репутации. // Но если новый движок действительно решит проблемы с «апаньем», то да, предложение не имеет особого смысла.

Comment: @СашаЧерных Не то чтобы проблема с большим количеством мелких правок решится целиком и полностью — при явной сортировке по дате редактирования вопросы будут "апаться", — просто это не будет сказываться на большинстве пользователей, только на любителях этой конкретной сортировки. К слову, сортировку по дате редактирования лично я использую на Мете — траффик маленький, поэтому удобно следить за всеми изменениями.

Answer (score 14):

Этой галочкой смогут пользоваться

- спамеры, чтобы менее заметно врезать рекламные дополнения в вопрос. (Нередко предлагаемая правка натыкается на роборевьюера и принимается вне зависимости от качества);
- участники-спорщики и вандалы, чтобы совсем незаметно продвигать свою точку зрения или подменять точку зрения автора;

Поэтому если и разрешать, то не раньше чем с тысяч пяти репутации.

Comment: > Нередко предлагаемая правка натыкается на роборевьюера и принимается вне зависимости от качества

// Это как? Вроде бы все правки участников с репутацией < 2000 проходят экспертную проверку. Спам и вандализм обнаружится, а к его внёсшему будут применены административные меры. // Моё предложение в большей степени для опытных участников, выполняющих рутинную работу вроде добавления/удаления/изменения меток. // Разрешение помечать правки «малыми» только при достижении определённой репутации поддерживаю.

Comment: Я считаю, предложение ТС правильное. Ни к чему забивать главную сменой меток, запятыми и т.п. А поскольку правят все кому не лень, то эта фича должна быть доступна независимо от уровня репутации.

Comment: @СашаЧерных роборевьювер - это участник с 2000+ репутации, который сидит в очереди проверок и жмет "выглядит нормально" на все подряд (за исключением явного вандализма).

Comment: @PashaPash причем явный вандализм (автопроверка) настолько очевиден, что я удивлюсь если хотя бы кто-то его не замечает с первой миллисекунды )

Answer (score 7):

> Чем выше сообщение в обновляющемся списке вопросов, тем больше вероятность получить за него плюс

Получить на него какую-то реакцию - да, но почему плюс-то? Можно и минус словить.
Да и вообще, спрашивающего скорее интересует ответ на вопрос, чем плюсы.

> Изменённое сообщение выносится на заглавную даже если подправить в нём запятую.

А Дух поднимает вопросы вообще просто так. В этом нет ничего плохого, пока речь не идёт о массовых правках, забивающих всю главную старыми вопросами.

> Правки, помеченные как «малые», не будут выноситься на заглавную.

Получается функционал для тех, кто хочет везде ходить и всё править по мелочи?
Автор же не воспользуется этим - он заинтересован во всплытии его вопроса.

Comment: > Получается функционал для тех, кто хочет везде ходить и всё править по мелочи? — Именно. Опытные участники на Stack Overflow совершают множество правок, которые можно было бы охарактеризовать как малые.