# Чистота главной страницы от старых вопросов

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, использование-метки

На Stack Overflow обращаются много новичков и опытных пользователей. Новички хотят узнать ответы на обыденные вопросы, которые скорее всего ранее задавались. Многие пользователи, которые в основном отвечают на вопросы, первым делом смотрят на те, которые на главной странице, а потом уже идут в **Вопросы -> Новые**.

Уже сколько дней в подряд я замечал, что пользователи [Утка Учится Уму](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/14963/%D0%A3%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%A3%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%A3%D0%BC%D1%83), [Vadim Ovchinnikov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/220571/vadim-ovchinnikov) и другие поднимают вверх старые вопросы на которые уже ответили давно или на проблемы, которые уже не актуальны в наше время. Много вопросов, которые ушли с главной остаются без ответа.

Я понимаю, что чистота меток нужное дело, много вопросов отсеивается из меток, которые они не затрагивает. Но не стоит ли редактировать новые вопросы, которые актуальны в данный момент, а не понимать антиквариат с 2012 года.

Как вы смотрите на такую деятельность?

Comment: `Многие пользователи, которые в основном отвечают на вопросы, первым делом смотрят на те, которые на главной странице, а потом уже идут в Вопросы -> Новые.` - чем это доказано и подтверждено? можно увидеть подтверждение сего факта? ..........`и другие пользователи поднимают вверх старые вопросы на которые уже ответили давно` - это еще что... тут кто-то вообще хочет на [субботник](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4392/)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, у меня друзей 4-5 тут отвечают. Я у всех спросил, как они на это смотрят вообще. Сообщения из ВК я вам не буду показывать, пожалуй. Как раз автор "субботника" этим занимается тоже

Comment: 4-5 — это не несколько сотен активных пользователей ;-)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ну это уже что-то )

Comment: @Yuri, ну пусть 4-5 друзей пожалуют на мету, спорные вопросы по сайту обсуждаются тут а не в чатике вк

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, увы - увы, они меня удалили после этой темы ;D Так что я остался один

Comment: @Yuri Меня тоже добавьте в этот вопрос, я тоже вопросы старые редактировал. А то вся слава Утке достаётся :)

Comment: @Yuri ну что-то, не что-то, а, всё таки, ресурсом пользуются не только они)) Поэтому говорить за большинство — не правильно. Вот если б статистика была, графики, диаграммы, научные статьи, нобелевская премия в области просмотра страниц на ruSO - куда ни шло. А так... Ну вот моя бабушка вообще не ходит на ruSO. Следовательно ruSO не нужно? )))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, как не посещает?! Быстро научи бабулю кодингку )

Comment: @Yuri Моя бабушка курррит трубббку. И этого ей достаточно.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, трубку курит бабушка моя... ты в php и безопасности разбираешься?

Answer (score 6):

На самом деле, он таким образом очищает сайт, не вижу ничего плохого в этом.

Comment: Утка - санитар сайта!

Answer (score 5):

Я полагаю, что большинство завсегдатаев сайта через некоторое время отвыкают пользоваться заглавной -- они подписываются на теги, которые им интересны и просматривают именно их.

Самому когда-то было интересно читать заглавную, особенно языки, с которыми не сталкивался. Чисто для расширения кругозора. Потом надоело.

Так что чистота заглавной меня волнует крайне мало. От слова "совсем".
А вот чистота сайта и меток -- очень волнует, потому что все мы пользуемся поиском и для поиска крайне важны именно заголовки и метки.

Процитирую также [этот ответ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2922/213987):

> Забудьте про существование "главной" страницы. На нашем сайте старая
>   версия движка, в новой версии "главной" страницы нет. Соответственно,
>   и проблемы с правками и "апаньем" нет.

Вообще, мне странно, что вы не апеллируете к более сильному (для меня по крайней мере) аргументу, что забиваются очереди проверок. А забивается, да. Всплыл вопрос - ему дали новый ответ (не посмотрев, что там уже пяток вопросов с плюс 15 и выше), потом ещё, потом что-то начали править... Сейчас же каникулы, проверяющих стало меньше.

Я так скажу. Я ничего плохо в действиях по очистке базы не вижу, более того -- приветствую, т.к. считаю цель хорошей. И медальку пусть получает, хоть какая-то награда за неоплачиваемую работу.

А что сейчас каникулы -- даже в плюс играет: вопросов мало задаётся, активность меньше.

И право, я думаю, что если бы вы без раздражения [в чате] спросили -- то не было бы такого повода для конфликта.

К тому же, есть ещё несколько пользователей-новичков, которые пришли недавно и активно пиарят свой продукт -- вот они-то почему залезают в старьё и дают какие-то новые ответы, переписывая практически один-в-один чужие вопросы. Рерайт, как это называют seo'шники.

Оставьте им, пусть пишут.

И автор субботника (раз уже его вспомнили в комментариях) тоже делает хорошее дело. Пусть там что-то в очередях проверок забивается -- но и разгребается тоже активно и с энтузиазмом.